# Symfony 3 Unique constraint error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

I am getting the following error while adding a UniqueEntity constraint on the email field of my User entity.

> Attempted to load class "Unique" from namespace
>   "\Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints". Did you forget a "use"
>   statement for another namespace?

If I remove the validation the error disappears. The contents of my `validation.yml` file are as followed.

```
LB\CoreBundle\Entity\User:
constraints:
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [email]
            groups: [registration,userEdit]
```

I have tried importing the validation constraint in my `User.php` file but the error still persists. Any help to get rid of this error is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your yml there are 4 sapces before the constraints keyword?

Comment: The error message is talking about a class named `Unique` (not `UniqueEntity`). Do you have a reference to that class anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="cab_fos_user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class User extends BaseUser
```

Comment: I am not using annotations in the project. So, using annotations just for getting rid of this error is not a good idea